# Different serializers for different objects in a single queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

For a ForeignKey relationship, how can I change the serializer used based off some criteria?

```
# models.py

class Relationship(models.Model):
    ...

class Item(models.Model):
    relationships = ForeignKey(Relationship)
```

```
class OddPKSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ...

class EvenPKSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ...

class ItemSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    # relationships = OddPKSerializer and/or EvenPKSerializer(many=True)
    # depending on some criteria

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ["relationships"]

    # Where for example, OddPKSerializer is used if
    # the specific relationship object has an odd pk
    # and EvenPKSerializer is used for even pks
```

In my actual use case, I'm looking to serialize differently based on the ForeignKey object's class. (I'm using proxy models so a single ForeignKey field can point to different classes.)

I've tried using `SerializerMethodField` but that only seems to act on the "Item" object and not the "Relationship" objects that I'm looking to serialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
class OddPKSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ...

class EvenPKSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ...

class SwitchSerializer():
    item = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_item(self, obj):
        if obj.pk/2 == 0:
            return EvenPKSerializer(obj).data
        return OddPKSerializer(obj).data

class ItemSerializer():
    item = SwitchSerializer(many=True)
```